# How does string theory account for the three generations of quarks and leptons?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory

Matter is mostly made up of the first generation of quarks and leptons: the up and down quark and the electron and electron neutrino.

There are two other generations that are heavier versions and are unstable.

How does string theory account for this?

Does it for example see the other two generations as 'resonances',

Does it predict an infinite tower of such resonances and thus higher generations?

Comment: Not really sure why this question has garnered a couple of down votes so quickly. Surely its important for string theory to explain the particles of the standard model?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22559/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I didn't place the downvotes but I would imagine it could relate to the fact there is a very [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265839/does-string-theory-explain-the-existence-of-3-generations-of-quarks-leptons) already here. Or perhaps that the question is about string theory, a lot of people ask about it without really knowing what they're asking for (no offense). The summary of any answer will probably be "That depends who you're asking."

Comment: It's been a long time since I took that string theory class in grad school, but from what I recall one can draw a neat connection between the topology of the compactified dimensions and the number of generations in the low-energy theory.  I wrote a [review paper on the subject which my professor never bothered to take down,](http://hamilton.uchicago.edu/~sethi/Teaching/P484-W2004/calabi-yau.pdf) which might be useful and provide you with pointers to further reading.  (Or it might be completely wrong;  like I said, it's been a long time since I thought about this stuff.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: that for the ref.

Comment: @lio Elammalf: sure, I wouldn't say that I know anything about string theory even after taking classes on it for my masters.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I've looked at the linked question - the answers are too general to really help. They do say that the number of generations is tied to the topology of the compact dimension which tallies with Michael Seiferts comment and which is useful - though I think I had known this once, but forgotten.

Comment: When a definite string theory model is decided upon, it will *have to embed* the standard model in its possible groupings. Thats the idea, that string theories with their vibrational levels have the group structure for the standard model groups.